# Java: Possible to consolidate empty subdirectories for packages that only contain other packages?

Tags: java, package, subdirectory

Good afternoon, all.

I'm not too hopeful for a "yes" here, but if anyone can figure it out, the folks at SO can.

I have a Java project that has the following package structure:

```
src
|-net
| |-binarymuse
|   |-gwt
|     |-client
|     | |-ui
|     |   |-project
|     |     |-Project.java
|     |-Project.gwt.xml
|-overview.html
```

I would like to consolidate the empty subdirectories in the src/ folder so that instead of `/src/net/binarymuse/gwt/client/ui/project/` I'd have `/src/net.binarymuse.gwt/client.ui.project/`. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse does that for you. It changes the presentation (Package Explorer) without modifying the directory structure.

Comment: @Dolph: Mostly for ease-of-browsing on a web-based explorer.
@Willi: Thanks, but I'm actually trying to modify the directory structure.

Comment: Sounds like a better file browser would be a more trivial solution :)

Comment: Absolutely! However, as is often the case, I have no control over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to write a classloader that works like this, perhaps even by subclassing [URLClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't collapse the directories on disk, no, but some IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) will do it automatically when they show the class hierarchy